# How can I get the text of a list item in a draggable div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

I've been trying to fix this to no avail.

I have a container div and a product div. The products are draggable, and the container is droppable and sortable, and accepts only products. The products are multiple list items. I have used the helper function in the draggable event to create a list item, and append the multiple list items to it, to be sent to the container. However, what I actually want is to collect the text from all the list items and club it all into one list item. How do I do that?

HTML CODE - PRODUCT

```
<div class="phrase product ui-draggable">
<ul>
        <li class="bit-box">Atlanta<a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="bit-box">London<a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="bit-box">Mumbai<a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="bit-input"><input type="text" class="maininput" /></li>
</ul>
```

HTML CODE - CONTAINER

```
<div id="container" style="border: 2px solid red; height: 400px;" class="ui-droppable ui-sortable ui-state-highlight">
<li class="containerproduct">Rio</li>
<li class="containerproduct">Santiago</li>
<li class="containerproduct">Atlanta London Mumbai</li>
```

The last item is what the container should have when the corresponding product is dragged to the container.

THE JQUERY

```
    $(".product").draggable({
    helper: function (e,ui) {
        return $("<li class=\"containerproduct\">asd</li>").append($(this).find('.bit-box').clone().removeClass());
    },
    axis: 'y',
    revert : true
    });
```

Right now, it's all saved as list items, [i.e. all on separate lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwb8P.png)

Comment: What is the code that gives you the output image?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/parikramatic/QS2RV/  This is close to the real code. You cannot any new tags apart from the existing one, but if you did, you get each tag on a different line after dragging

Comment: This isn't the exact code since it's missing some libraries. I saw what the code was doing, and reduced it to what I've asked above.

Comment: What is the specific line of code that generates the output?

Comment: return $("<li class=\"containerproduct\">asd</li>").append($(this).find('.bit-box').clone().removeClass());

It finds the (.bit-box)es and clones them. I've found that removing the clone and just adding a plain div hangs the page.

Comment: What about the `li` with "Rio"?

Comment: Those two list items already exist in the container (Rio and Santiago). When the <div class="phrase product ui-draggable"> is dragged, it is converted into the Atlanta London Mumbai list item, because it takes the text of all three list items in the div, and combines it into one. Hope that helps :)

Comment: What is the exact output you are getting when you drag and drop the `div` with "Atlanta, London, Mumbai"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using

- first(), which I used to clone the list item, and
- each(), which I used to iterate over the bit-box list items to get their text

Bit of appending, and we're home free :)

```
            $(".product").draggable({
                distance: 10,
                cursor: "move",
                helper: function (e, ui) {
                    var newListItem = $(this).find('.bit-box').first().clone().removeClass().addClass("ui-state-default");
                    var fullCommand = "";
                    $(this).find('.bit-box').each(function( index ) {
                        fullCommand += $(this).text() + " ";
                    });

                    newListItem.text(fullCommand);
                    return (newListItem);
                },
                revert : true
                });
```